# has_many conditions or proc on foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many, has-one

I have a has_many association between two models using a date as both the foreign and primary key for each model.

It works perfectly one way but not the other.

Works

```
has_one :quiz_log, :primary_key => :start_at, :foreign_key => :start_at
```

Doesn't work

```
has_many :event_logs, :primary_key => :start_at, :foreign_key => :start_at
```

The reason being (i think) because the start_at on QuizLog is a `date` and the start_at on EventLog is a `datetime`.  So it returns nil trying to match the exact datetime on a simple date.

How can I cast the foreign_key start_at on the second statement to convert it first from datetime to simply date so it will match the second model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do it without using finder_SQL, but this should work.

```
has_many :event_logs, :finder_sql => proc { 
   "SELECT * FROM event_logs WHERE DATE(event_logs.start_at) = '#{start_at}'" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the title twice, I understand what you are asking for.  May be something like the following would work?:

```
has_many :event_logs, :primary_key => :start_at, :conditions => proc { "start_date = '#{event_logs.start_date.to_date}'" }
```

Comment: I got "output error: #<SystemStackError: stack level too deep>" when I tried that. ;-(

Comment: this fails because you referencing `event_log` in it's declaration.
try `has_many :event_logs, :primary_key => :start_at, :conditions => proc { "DATE(start_date) = '#{start_date}'" }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I would use something like:

```
def event_logs
  EventLogs.where('event_logs.start_at >= ? AND event_logs.start_at < ?', start_at, start_at + 1.day)
end
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a date range but rather a single date, also I'm also using has_many through for another model as well, I'm not sure a method would keep the functionality on other models?

Comment: Why a range? because you tell in your question that you have a datetime (has hours). And no, i don't think that the has_many through Works.