# remove foreign_key in Rails 5 has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In attempting to build a materialized path model hierarchy (as detailed [here](https://medium.com/notes-from-a-messy-desk/representing-trees-in-postgresql-cbcdae419022)), I wanted to figure out how to solve the N+1 problem the other describes at the bottom.

The obvious solution is to define `children` as an association and include it instead of making it a method. The problem is that Rails no longer supports `find_by_sql` and even when you add a proc to a `has_many`, Rails insists on prepending `"#{relation}.#{foreign_key} = #{id} AND"` to the SQL that is generated (eg `"nodes"."node_id" = $1 AND`, see below).

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180110025405) do
  create_table "nodes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "path", default: [], array: true
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["path"], name: "index_nodes_on_path", using: :gin
  end
end


class Node < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, ->(node) { where(path: node.path + [node.id]) }, class_name: "Node", foreign_key: nil
end

irb(main):060:0> Node.last.children
  Node Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes" ORDER BY "nodes"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column nodes.node_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes" WHERE "nodes"."node_id" = $1 ...
                                             ^
: SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes" WHERE "nodes"."node_id" = $1 AND "nodes"."path" = $2 LIMIT $3
```

Is there a way to make a custom `has_many` like this work in recent versions of Rails?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436829/has-many-conditions-or-proc-on-foreign-key

Comment: Though it may violate a couple of formal design principles, you may be able to store a node's path as a JSON string instead of an array and use it as a foreign key for the `children` relationship. Then you could store the combination of a node's path and ID in another JSON string (e.g. `absolute_path` or `full_path`) for use as a primary key. See the [serialization api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html). The issue is you must now update two columns when changing a node's position in the tree.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio as stated, I want to use a recent version of Rails, which no longer supports `finder_sql`

Comment: @w_hile yeah I'm afraid that's not really workable. Denormalizes data, creating more than a single source of truth :(

Comment: @steve Sometimes it's the right move to bend the rules if it saves substantial cost. Denormalization is workable, though not ideal. If you found a way to remove the `"#{relation}.#{foreign_key} = #{id}` from the query, the pre-loader built into Rails still relies on an explicit foreign key (see [this file on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb#L41)) and would need to be modified for this use case. If you don't want to denormalize, writing a custom pre-loader may be your best option.

Comment: @w_hile yeah I mean at that point I might as well add `parent_node_id` and give up on the materialized path altogether right?
I guess I should ask a new question "how to write a custom preloader in rails" that might be more useful to in a variety of situations anyway 